# Break huge URLs so they don't overflow

Tags: url, css, word-wrap, line-breaks

Is there a way to force huge urls such as `http://www.google.de/search?q=65daysofstatic&hl=de&safe=off&prmd=ivnsl&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=P9NkToCRMorHsgaunaClCg&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CBkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1697&bih=882` break when rendered in the website? I'd rather shorten it but where I'm working they've asked me to show the entire url but I only have a space of 320px to show it and it overflows.

Overflow:hidden, isn't an option either and adding a style to the td where the url is contained is simply ignored.

Comment: Apparently, the answer is yes.  SO seems to simply wrap them in a code block.

Comment: You mean beside javascript manipulations that would insert an abbreviated version of the URL ? Do you consider the option to use an external URL shortener service, too ?

Comment: One possibility would be to replace `'&'` with `' &'` - then it would wrap as it reaches the allocated width.  Unfortunately, if somebody wants to copy it and paste into a browser, they would have to remove the spaces manually.

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr put them between like this? `<a href="#">huge url</a>`

Comment: @AleksG that shouldn't happen as they only need to see the complete url (as far as I know), but the URL's are added automatically using php, where should I go about doing this?

Comment: @Aleks - that's only because I hadn't fired up web inspector to see how SO was handling it and hadn't updated it yet.

Comment: no put them inside, <a href="huge url">User Friendly CLICK ME</a>

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr a but the thing is the link must be completely visible, hence my problem

Comment: @Luis - is the link itself really contextual or is this just a silly requirement that you need a find a way to talk them out of? It doesn't seem reasonable that a very long link would be usable by a human directly (except to click on, which the `<code></code>` solution would help much with).

Comment: @tvanfosson probably the best thing would be to find a way to talk them out of, let me try the <code></code>

Comment: @Luis oops, just re-read my comment.  Should have been *wouldn't help much*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

CSS3 has a new feature:

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

You can see a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JoseFaeti/Fqbgu/) (you must have a browser compatible with that new feature).

It's also the same tecnique adopted by StackOverflow, if you examine your long URL you will notice.

Alternatively you can try [Hyphenator](http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/).

Answer (score 29):

In Chrome, `word-wrap` does not work. You should use:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

If you want to apply it only on a tags, then you should use:

```
a {word-break: break-all;}
```

Note that `break-all` will even split words, so a word can start on one line and end on another, that's why it's a good idea to apply it only on `a` tags. If you know that your links always contain words (e.g. are not something like mylink/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 ), then you can apply the following at the body tag level (this way a word is not split onto 2 lines):

```
body {word-break: break-word;}
```

Comment: ``word-wrap:break-word;`` didn't work for me (on Chrome). I think this should be elevated as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! Wasn't working on Chrome and it was killing me! This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

```
-ms-word-break: break-all;
     word-break: break-all;

     // Non standard for webkit
     word-break: break-word;

-webkit-hyphens: auto;
   -moz-hyphens: auto;
        hyphens: auto;
```

The above works in Internet Explorer 8+, Firefox 6+, iOS 4.2, Safari 5.1+ and Chrome 13+.

Answer (score 3):

overflow-wrap to the rescue:

> Note: In contrast to word-break, overflow-wrap will only create a
> break if an entire word cannot be placed on its own line without
> overflowing.

it has pretty much full browser support and will help when your long word (E.G URLs) cannot fit in the available space

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

Comment: I confirm. This is the correct answer as of today @Tsundoku

Answer (score 2):

I use this rule to affect only anchors.

```
.my-paragraph p a[href] {
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below **CSS properties** for show long text URL to short...

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
display: inline-block;
max-width: 40%;
```